# Xdebug interrupts the running of PHP script

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, xdebug

I'm using Netbeans 7.3 and xDebugon WAMP. Here is my configuration of xDebugin php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

If I put a break point on my ajax script, it stops on the break point. If I go line by line with F8 to the end of the script, I get "500 Internal Server Error" as a result. Without the break point, everything is OK. I even get this error on my controller action in Yii. If I go with break point line by line, I get 500 error in the browser. Without the break point, it's working fine. I tried with other versions of xDebug, it's the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had some invalid watches in my debug window that triggered these errors, maybe that is the case in your case too? Try clearing your watches window, maybe it helps.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

500 (Internal Server Error) in phpstorm 9.0 when enabling xdebug breakpoints.

Validate your whatches for php session. Errors in whatches can generate errors in executing php code. Errors disapears when you disable xdebug listening or correct/remove whatches.

Comment: That did it for me. I had some watches from a previous debug session in the watches list, that php couldn't evaluate. removed them and it works again. thanks!