# PhpStorm Xdebug interrupts after a while with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm new to PhpStorm. I tried to use debugging for debuggin a Webpage and I configured it 
After starting the debugger, it works for 40 seconds and then  I get on the browser "500 Internal Server Error"

At this question [Xdebug interrupts the running of PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579929/xdebug-interrupts-the-running-of-php-script) they suggested to clear the watches. But in my Debugger there are no watches.
I use the PhpStorm with Ubuntu 14.04 and the web page is running on Apache

I used Eclipse before and I did not had this problem with XDebug.

Do someone has an idea?

Comment: What do you debug -- a web page or CLI script? If a web page -- what web server serves it (Apache etc)? How PHP is run there (fastCGI or something else)? Please measure how long it takes to get the error (30 seconds constantly or some random time)?

Comment: it's a web page. the error appears after 40 seconds. it's running on apache

Comment: How PHP is run by Apache? If it's the same then it simply could be FastCGI limit (Apache will kill the script that runs over the specified time limit). If that's so then you will have to increase such limit to 3-5-10 mins (whatever is acceptable for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user LazeOne (who added a comment) I found the solution.

I added to my apache configuration (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) the following line
`FcgidIOTimeout 600 # for 10 minutes`

and the debugger does not interrupt for the next 10 minutes